# How to setup format of datetime picker in easyadminbundle?

Tags: symfony, datetimepicker, symfony2-easyadmin

How can I change the default format used by the datetime picker of easyadminbundle?

I understand I must change something in `config.yml` in type_options of field property. Or setup some different datetime format. But how or where?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
easy_admin:
  design:
    assets:
        js: ['assets/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js(Your Date picker Js)', 'assets/js/initDatePicker.js (Your code to initialize date picker on base of class "datepicker")']
        css: ['assets/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css(Path of your datepicker css)']
  form:
     title: 'Your Title'
     fields:
        - { property: 'displayFrom', label: 'Display From', type_options: {'widget': 'single_text', 'format': 'dd/MM/yyyy H:mm', 'attr': {'class': 'datepicker'}} }
```

Just replace path of javascript and css and init datepicker, Also replace the field (displayFrom) with your form field.

Comment: Problem is, that: "Leave empty" functionality for setting field on NULL, is now gone :(

Comment: Means you do not want to mark that field as required, am i right? Form should be submitted if user will not select the date. am i right?

Comment: Yes, problem is, that now when I click on Leave empty checkbox, field won't hide and value is not setup on null.

Image:

http://imgur.com/a/hNpVU

Comment: If you check the check box then what will be the database value after submit the form for these 2 fields which you have in image.

Comment: Yes, and normally would this field after hitting the button hide and value would be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

In yml you can use datepicker class like this.

```
form:
   title: 'Create User'
   fields:           
        - { other fileds ...}
        - { property: 'expiredAt', label: 'Credentials expired at', type_options: {'widget': 'single_text', 'format': 'dd/MM/yyyy H:mm', 'attr': {'class': 'datepicker'}} }
```

replace expiredAt with your field name. Hope this may helpful to you or anyone else.

Comment: Problem is, that: "Leave empty" functionality for setting field on NULL, is now gone :(

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out, here is my solution:

Install:

https://github.com/stephanecollot/DatetimepickerBundle

config.yml:

```
- { property: 'credentialsExpireAt', type_options: {'widget': 'single_text', 'format': 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', 'attr': {'class': 'datepicker' }} }

assets:        
        css:
             - 'bundles/scdatetimepicker/css/datetimepicker.css'           
        js:
             - 'bundles/scdatetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'
             - 'bundles/easyadmin/javascript/init.js'
```

init.js:

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({        
        minuteStep: 15
    });
});
```

Problem is, that: "Leave empty" functionality for setting field on NULL, is now gone :(

Comment: I've looked at the source code: there is made a check if the field is a date and if the field is nullable. You can set `nullable: false` to remove the "Leave empty" button: `- { property: 'credentialsExpireAt', nullable: false, type_options: {'widget': 'single_text', 'format': 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', 'attr': {'class': 'datepicker' }} }`. But now you may have to implement this functionality by yourself if you need this (but clearing e.g. the input field for an empty date (null) is okay I think).